# How to put images into a grid with css?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a grid sort of style of images and having a box underneath. Is there an easier way to achieve this look?
I am trying to replicate the [layout shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0E6yq.jpg)

At the moment this is where I am at with positioning:
[Screenshot of what I have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jehQZ.jpg)

I want the far right image to be at the right margin, and also have a bit of spacing between the images.

#### My HTML so far:

```
      <section id="trending">

       <h> TRENDING REVIEWS </h>

       <div class="review1">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/ramenzundo.jpg"  alt="ramenzundo" width="300" height="300" /></a>
         <a href="#"><img src="images/charlierabbit.jpg" alt="charlie" width="300" height="300" /></a>
         <a href="#"><img src="images/ichiran.jpg" alt="ichiran" width="300" height="300" /></a>
      </div>


   <div class="below1">
       <p>RAMEN ZUNDO</p>
   </div>


   <div class="reviews4">
       <a href="#"><img src="images/downandout.jpg" alt="down" width="300" height="300" /></a>
       <a href="#"><img src="images/speedos.jpg" alt="speedo" width="300" height="300" /></a>
       <a href="#"><img src="images/tinygiant.jpg" alt="tiny" width="300" height="300" /></a>
   </div>

     </section>
```

#### My CSS:

```
  #trending {
      float:left;
      width:960px;
      height:1000px;
      background-color:#fdded9;
  }


  #trending h{
      position:absolute;
      font-size: 30px;
      font-family: 'Economica', sans-serif;
      color:white;
      background-color: black;
  }

  .review1 {
     padding-top:50px;
     margin-right: 30px;
  }

 .below1{
    vertical-align:bottom;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:black;
  }
```

Comment: think about it logically - to have a grid, you need a X by X space. Let's say x = 4 for ease. So, 4 per row leads to this 4 divs inside a parent row div. Now, css wise, think of what you need. The images inside the row container needs to be inline and equal heights and widths. `display: inline` will get them inline, width and height can be set to whatever you want. I usually go around the 22% width-mark due to added padding and margins.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? just make sure you know what kind of structure you are looking for then build around that.

Here each row have a container `<div class="rowContainer">` contain 3 images, for each image use `<div class="review1">`. For content below image use:

```
  <div class="below1">
    <p>RAMEN ZUNDO</p>
  </div>
```

```css
#trending {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.review1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 15px;
}

.rowContainer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<section id="trending">

  <h> TRENDING REVIEWS </h>

  <div class="rowContainer">
    <div class="review1">
      <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="ramenzundo" width="300" height="300" /></a>
      <div class="below1">
        <p>RAMEN ZUNDO</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="review1">
      <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="charlie" width="300" height="300" /></a>
      <div class="below1">
        <p>RAMEN ZUNDO</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="review1">
      <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="ichiran" width="300" height="300" /></a>
      <div class="below1">
        <p>RAMEN ZUNDO</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="rowContainer">
    <div class="review1">
      <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="ramenzundo" width="300" height="300" /></a>
      <div class="below1">
        <p>RAMEN ZUNDO</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="review1">
      <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="charlie" width="300" height="300" /></a>
      <div class="below1">
        <p>RAMEN ZUNDO</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="review1">
      <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="ichiran" width="300" height="300" /></a>
      <div class="below1">
        <p>RAMEN ZUNDO</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Grid</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body{
            font-family: 'Economica', sans-serif;
        }
        .heading{
              position:absolute;
              font-size: 30px;
              color:white;
              background-color: black;
          }

        #trending {
              margin: 0 auto;
              width:960px;
              height:1000px;
              background-color:#fdded9;
              clear: both;
          }

          .grid-container{
            clear: both;
            padding-top: 70px;
          }

          .grid {
             border: 4px solid #444;
             overflow: hidden;
             float: left;
             width: 250px;
             margin: 15px 27px;
             text-align: center;
          }

          .grid a{
            overflow: hidden;
            color: #000;
            text-decoration: none;
          }

          .grid p{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 20px 0px; 
            background-color: #C3D7CC;
          }

         .below1{
            vertical-align:bottom;
            width:300px;
            height:200px;
            background-color:black;
          }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <section id="trending">
        <h1 class="heading"> TRENDING REVIEWS </h1>

          <div class="grid-container">
             <div class="grid">
               <a href="#">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x250" alt="ichiran" width="250" height="300" />
                <p>RAMEN ZUNDO</p>
               </a>
             </div>
             <div class="grid">
               <a href="#">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x250" alt="ichiran" width="250" height="300" />
                <p>RAMEN ZUNDO</p>
               </a>
             </div>
             <div class="grid">
               <a href="#">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x250" alt="ichiran" width="250" height="300" />
                <p>RAMEN ZUNDO</p>
               </a>
            </div>

             <div class="grid">
               <a href="#">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x250" alt="down" width="250" height="300" />
                <p>RAMEN ZUNDO</p>
               </a>
             </div>
             <div class="grid">
               <a href="#">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x250" alt="speedo" width="250" height="300" />
                <p>RAMEN ZUNDO</p>
               </a>
             </div>
             <div class="grid">
               <a href="#">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x250" alt="tiny" width="250" height="300" />
                <p>RAMEN ZUNDO</p>
               </a>
            </div>
          </div>

     </section>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are new to HTML and CSS - know that this is still one of the hardest things to do well. The question isn't really about images either. Making a 'grid' layout of elements is what you are doing. An image *is* and element - just like a div - but in this case - your elements are inside a parent.

Ensuring your markup is as great as it can be, is the first step:

```
<ul class='thing-list'>

  <li class='thing'>
    <a class='link' href='#'>
      <figure>
        <img src='https://placehold.it/800x1000' alt='thing poster'>
      </figure>
      <h1 class='title'>Title</h1>
      <div class='rating'>
        xxx
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

This would live in some parent element for layout management.

Grids are almost always a list of something being spit out by an array of data, so you should actually use a list - maybe even an 'ordered' one. `<ol>`

Once you have solid markup - you have many choices of how to get a grid going. Most of what you choose will depend on what browsers you have to support.

Use a site like this: https://caniuse.com/#search=grid  to check for browser compatibility for any CSS stuff.

- You can make the list items `display: inline-block;` and they will lineup and break to the next line.
- You could use a table layout (put the info into a table element)
- You can use floats to align then next to each other (make sure to clearfix their parent - or `overflow: hidden;` it in the short term)
- You can use CSS grid (look that up)
- Or you can **use flexbox**, which is what I suggest. The only downside to this, is that you'll likely want to use a preprocessor and autoprefixer to ensure you don't have to write the tricky browser prefixes by hand. *(this is not really a downside - but might be scary if you haven't used one.) I suggest codekit for beginners - or use the autoprefixer built into codepen for practice.*

I HIGHLY recommend you try ALL the ways I mentioned - so you can learn the quirks of each.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/0egLgmge/

This is a great guide to help you with the specifics: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

figure {
  margin: 0;
}

figure img { /* make img's in figures responsive to their parent */
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.thing-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direct: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.thing-list .thing {
  flex-basis: 30%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.thing-list .thing .link {
  display: block; /* this has children that are block - so it HAS to be block */
}  

.thing-list .thing figure {
  /* */
}

.thing-list .thing .title {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: lightgreen;
  color: white;
}

.thing-list .thing .rating {
  padding: 10px; /* you can use flexbox for these stars too */
}
```

For different screen sizes - you'll need to use @media queries to change the style rules based on screen size.

You're also going to need this: https://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/